# Does MathJax cache SVG content?

Tags: svg, mathjax

I have extracted LaTeX content from **.tex** file, that I put on the website and choose **SVG** as output, because it provides the smallest possible size so I consider that It will be the best choise also because of his speed and widest versatility. I know, that **.js** files that contains **configurations** are cached on the disk in the browser for a few days (depends on the config of the web) or CDN file, but there could be problem with availability of that page, but what about **SVG content?**

**Does it also cache on the disc?**

Thank you

Comment: MathJax questions are off topic on this site, if you click the mathjax tag link above there are links to the mathjax help list, or stack overflow mathjax tag